# PHP Upload for Fails

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have an upload form where I want to allow users to upload images and videos but when I submit the form, it tosses the error message I have set into the else statement. What did I do wrong?

```
<?php

 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
  $extension = end($temp);
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)
  && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["upload"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["upload"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else 
      {

        $fileName = $temp[0].".".$temp[1];
        $temp[0] = rand(0, 3000); //Set to random number
        $fileName;

      if (file_exists("content/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
        echo $_FILES["upload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
      else
        {
        $newfilename = rand(1,99999).end(explode(".",$_FILES["upload"]["name"]));
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], "content/" . $newfilename);
        echo "Stored in: " . "content/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
      }
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Invalid file or connection failure.";
    }

 ?>
```

"Invalid file or connection failure." is the error message I get.

Comment: What kind of debugging did you already do?

Comment: Your issue is with the first `if` statement. Can you post your `<form>` code ?

Comment: Your file is clearly failing one of the many conditions at the top of your script. You'll have to work out which one. Add some debug code.

Comment: change both `$_FILES["file"]["name"];` to `$_FILES["upload"]["name"];` mismatched. Since there are others called `$_FILES["upload"]["name"])` or make the first parameters all the same.

Comment: You should also make an $allowedMimeTypes array and put all those values into it. Then in your `if` statement you only have to do an `in_array` comparison rather than that crazy long list.

Comment: You also have an issue with your random name, it's losing the dot for the file extension.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use however I don't insert temp randoms

```
<?php


$fileName = $files['upload']['name'];
$fileArray = explode('.', $fileName);
$extension = count($fileArray) - 1;
$extension = $fileArray[$extension];

// Put allowed file extensions in the following array   

$allowedExt = array("gif",
                    "avi",
                    "mp4",
                    "jpeg",
                    "jpg",
                    "pjpeg",
                    "x-png",
                    "png");

if(!in_array($extension, $allowedExt)){
// print error message here
exit;
}

$fileType = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
# Put allowed file mime types here as an extra check 
$allowedTypes = array("image/gif",
                      "video/avi",
                      "video/mp4",
                      "image/jpeg",
                      "image/jpg",
                      "image/pjpeg",
                      "image/x-png",
                      "image/png"); 

if(!in_array($fileType, $allowedTypes)){
// print error message here
exit;
}

// Add the rest of your code here as required

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the filename: `i1_small.jpg` to upload (which is a file I used from my computer)

The code that follows, will rename it to: `74447_i1_small.jpg` (using a random number from the `rand()` function that was already in your code)

You had mismatched parameter names.

For example:

`$_FILES["upload"]["name"])`
and
`$_FILES["file"]["name"])`

**These must match.**

HTML form  I used: (make sure the input matches `name="file"` as shown below)

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Try this out now:

```
<?php

 $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $extension = end($temp);
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/avi")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 100000)
  && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
      {
      echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
      }
    else 
      {

        // $fileName = $temp[0].".".$temp[1];


$fileName = $temp[0].".".$temp[1];


        $temp[0] = rand(0, 3000); //Set to random number
        $fileName;

      if (file_exists("content/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
        {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
        }
      else
        {
        $newfilename = rand(1,99999) . "_" . ($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "content/" . $newfilename);
        echo "Stored in: " . "content/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        }
      }
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Invalid file or connection failure.";
    }

 ?>
```